# How do I reset notification themes?

Tags: debian, openbox, notifications

I am on BunsenLabs (debian jessie 8.2). One day the notifications started looking like this.

[image: minimal notifications]

I don't remember messing with anything to with notification themes. If I select these options from the notification options, nothing happens.

[image: Selecting these options doesn't do anything]

How do I reset or fix this?

Comment: That's another notification daemon. Remove it and restart X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ipor-sircer noted, it was an extra notification daemon called `dunst` that was installed. I started getting regular notifications again after I have uninstalled it, logged out and logged in.